Permission error creating new file on Windows NFS share from RHEL 8 client
Set up a NFS share on a Windows Server 2022 box set up as:


On my RHEL 8 box, I can mount the share using:
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.4.195:/DOCLINKS /doclinks

The mount gets created, I can view directory contents and contents of files in the directory and modify existing files.  What I cannot do is create a new file in that directory. I even have the Everyone group in NTFS permissions on the server set to Full Control.
Permissions on the folder on the RHEL box are:
drwxrwxrwx+   2 nobody nobody   64 Nov 25 11:09 doclinks

What am I missing?
Regards,
Keith

first type just mount and observe all the mount parameters on /doclink specifically a rw; if it is ro then there you go.  Other thing to easily try to see if selinux  is the cause is to do a setenforce 0 then mount and test write capability.

Youre "missing" many NFS options. See the NFSsection ofman mount, try man mount.nfs`.
